# Need to decode, don't have key

Tags: decryption

So my friend gave me this monster of a code but I dont know WHAT it is and they said it can be solved as is ... I've been working on it for a week and its making me mad. Got any ideas?

GAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTCMBQGEQDAMBRGEYTAMBREAYDAMJRGAYTCMJAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTAMJRGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTAMJRGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYTCIBQGAYTCMBRGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMJQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJRGAYTAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYTAIBQGAYTCMJQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMJQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJRGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYTCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMJQGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMJQEAYDAMJRGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTAMJRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGAYTCMJAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBREAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYSAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYTAMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGEYSAMBQGEYTAMJRGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMJQEAYDAMJRGAYDCMBAGAYDCMJQGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJRGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDCMJAGAYDCMJQGAYDCIBQGAYTCMJQGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJRGAYTCMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGEYCAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDCMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYSAMBQGEYTAMJRGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYTCMBAGAYDCMJQGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYSAMBQGEYTAMBRGEQDAMBRGEYDCMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJQEAYDAMJRGAYDCMJAGAYDCMJQGEYTCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBREAYDAMJRGEYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGEYCAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGEYSAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGAYTCMJAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGAYTAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGEYSAMBQGEYTAMJRGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGEYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMJQGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBRGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJRGAYTAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYTAIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYTCMBAGAYDCMJQGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYSAMBQGEYTAMBRGEQDAMBRGEYDCMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYTAMBREAYDAMJRGEYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMBRGEYCAMBQGEYTAMBRGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTAMJRGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYTAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYSAMBQGEYTAMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDAMJQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGAYTAIBQGAYTCMBQGAYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMJREAYDAMJRGAYTAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYTCIBQGAYTCMBRGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYSAMBQGEYTCMBQGEQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYTAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTCMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJRGAYDAIBQGAYTCMBQGEYCAMBQGEYTAMJQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBREAYDAMJRGEYDAMJAGAYDCMJQGEYDAIBQGAYTCMJQGAYCAMBQGEYTAMJRGAQDAMBRGEYDCMJREAYDAMJQGAYDAMBAGAYDCMJQGEYDCIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDCMBQEAYDAMJRGAYDCMBAGAYDCMJQGAYTAIBQGAYTCMBRGAYCAMBQGEYTAMBQGAQDAMBRGEYDAMBQEA

Comment: This looks like homework., maybe ask your friend for a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Cryptanalysis is the study and anlysis of crypto systems.  You first need to identify possible cipher(s) which may have been used on this challenge.

Here's a page with a [description of a few types of techniques](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/) you may want to read. It will give you an idea of common simple ciphers that would likely have been used.

Here's a page from the same site that talks about [analyzing unknown ciphers](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/identifying-unknown-ciphers/).